# execution of javascript after dom ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, liferay

this question was posted several times and i looked at many solutions.

My Problem:

I want to execute `setAccordionActiv(false)` after the DOM is loaded.

```
function setAccordionActiv(paramActiv) {
    if(paramActiv) {
        $(".aui-toggler-content-wrapper").show();
    } else {
        $(".aui-toggler-content-wrapper").hide();
    }
}
```

`aui-toggler-content-wrapper` is part of AUI which is used in Liferay.

I tried using:

Another document ready() because they should be executed serialized

Answers from this Question: 
[forcing a jQuery ready block to run after all other ready blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549200/forcing-a-jquery-ready-block-to-run-after-all-other-ready-blocks)

Those are the answers in most Questions.

However none worked for me.

On the contrary `alert()` did work so `aui-toggler-content-wrapper` must be the reason.

If i execute `setAccordionActiv(false)` later for example via button click it does work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just wrap your function call inside $(document).ready. That should work.

Comment: so your problem is the .aui-toggler-content-wrapper doesnt exist of document ready?

Comment: yeah, kinda. but the program does not crash (nullpointer) and instead jumps over that command. at least it looks like it. maybe i should rephrase my prob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setAccordionActiv(false);
   ///////call function with ^^^parameter


 });
    function setAccordionActiv(paramActiv) {
        if(paramActiv) {
            $(".aui-toggler-content-wrapper").show();
        } else {
            $(".aui-toggler-content-wrapper").hide();
        }
    }
```

reference  **[.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function setAccordionActiv(paramActiv) {
        if (paramActiv) {
            $(".aui-toggler-content-wrapper").show();
        } else {
            $(".aui-toggler-content-wrapper").hide();
        }
    }
    setAccordionActiv(paramActiv);
}
```

Read [DOM ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)