# Are cookie read/write atomic in browser

Tags: javascript, html, concurrency

I am trying to implement a cross tab mutex for my needs. I found a implementation [here](http://balpha.de/2012/03/javascript-concurrency-and-locking-the-html5-localstorage/#comments).    which seems quite promising. Basically, it implements [Leslie Lamport's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm) with needs atomic read/writes for creating a mutex.

However it relies on localStorage providing atomic read/writes. This works well in most browsers except for Chrome.

So my question is, can I use cookie read/write instead? Are cookie reads/writes atomic in all mainstream browsers (IE, Chrome, Safari, Firefox)?

Comment: it's very necesary use cookies?

Comment: becouse localStorage now works great in chrome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither cookies, nor `localStorage` provide atomic transactions.

I think you might have misunderstood that blog post, it doesn't say that his implementation doesn't work in Chrome, it *does not rely on `localStorage` providing atomic read/writes*. He says that *normal* `localStorage` access is more volatile in Chrome. I'm assuming this is related to the fact that Chrome uses a separate process for each tab, whereas most other browsers tend to use a single process for all tabs. His code implements a locking system on top of `localStorage` which should protect against things getting overwritten.

Another solution would be to use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB). IndexedDB **does** provide atomic transactions. Being a new standard it is not supported in as many browsers as `localStorage`, but it does have good support in recent versions of Firefox, Chrome and IE10.

Comment: Nice tip about IndexedDB.  I second that the blog post was misunderstood. Chrome and Opera exhibit the most problems due to having multiple process/thread with access to the same LocalStorage parameters.  While each read or write operation is atomic a READ-TEST-MODIFY-WRITE sequence can not be guaranteed to be uninterrupted.  Typically in JavaScript you don't have to worry about having code pre-empted, however as LocalStorage is shared amongst multiple process/threads one can not rely this typical JavaScript behaviour.  The implementation described in the blog is to address this exact issue.

Comment: Note that for `localStorage`, single writes *are* atomic. See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-storage-interface ("The setItem() and removeItem() methods must be atomic with respect to failure. In the case of failure, the method does nothing.").

Answer (score 0):

No. Even if the browsers probably implement a read and a write lock on the cookie it won't protect you from changes that happens between a read and a consequent write. This is easy to see by looking at the [javascript API for cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html), there is no mutex functionality there...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this concurrency issue using localStorage today (two years alter..)

Scenario: Multiple tabs of a browser (e.g. Chrome) have identical script code that gets executed, basically at the same time (called by e.g. SignalR). The code reads and writes to localStorage. Since the tabs run in different processes but access the shared local storage collectively, reading and writing leads to undefined results since a locking mechanism is missing here. In my case I wanted to make sure that only one of the tabs actually works with the local storage and not all of them..

I tried the locking mechanism of Benjamin Dumke-von der Ehe metioned in the question above but got undesired results. So I decided to roll my own experimental code:

**localStorage lock:**

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(localStorage).lockRndId = new Date().getTime() + '.' + Math.random();
Object.getPrototypeOf(localStorage).lock = function (lockName, maxHold, callback) {
    var that = this;
    var value = this.getItem(lockName);
    var start = new Date().getTime();    
    var wait = setInterval(function() {
        if ((value == null) || (parseInt(value.split('_')[1]) + maxHold < start)) {
            that.setItem(lockName, that.lockRndId + '_' + start);
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (that.getItem(lockName) == (that.lockRndId + '_' + start)) {
                    clearInterval(wait);
                    try { callback(); }
                    catch (e) { throw 'exeption in user callback'; }
                    finally { localStorage.removeItem(lockName); }
                }
            }, 100);
        }        
    }, 200);        
};
```

**usage:**

localStorage.lock(*lockName*, *maxHold*, *callback*);

- *lockName* - a global scope unique name for the lock - string
- *maxHold* - the maximum time to protect the script in milliseconds - integer
- *callback* - the function containing the script that gets protected

**example:** "only play a sound in one tab"

```
//var msgSound = new Audio('/sounds/message.mp3');

localStorage.lock('lock1', 5000, function(){

    // only one of the tabs / browser processes gets here at a time
    console.log('lock aquired:' + new Date().getTime());

    // work here with local storage using getItem, setItem

    // e.g. only one of the tabs is supposed to play a sound and only if none played it within 3 seconds        
    var tm = new Date().getTime();
    if ((localStorage.lastMsgBeep == null)||(localStorage.lastMsgBeep <tm-3000)) {
       localStorage.lastMsgBeep = tm;
       //msgSound.play();                       
       console.log('beep');                        
    }  
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me... If I open the same URL in 10 separate tabs at the same time (or quickly), in the end the number is only stored 3 or 4 times in localStorage (running storeAnotherNumber function, so in this case, the result is like: 42,42,42,42)