# What to change in the Logout.js file so that a redirect to the registration page after I click the logout button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I implement authorization and registration in the application.

What I have already done:
If the user successfully validates the form, the form is sent to the local server and returns a response, this response contains a token, which I save in localStorage and with the help of: `history.push ("/ home");` I am redirecting to the home page. In addition, I wrote in the `Home`component:

```
const Home = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("myToken")
    return (
        <>
            {!token && <Redirect to="/" />}
            <Header/>
            <h1>Home page</h1>
        </>
    )
}
```

So that if there is no recorded token in localStorage, there is a redirect to the authorization page, that is, you can’t go to the home page if you unregistered user.

Now I made the `Logout` component, which when clicked, will remove the token from localStorage and as in the component `Home`, it is written:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem("myToken");
{!token && <Redirect to="/" />}
```

And after clicking Logout button should have been to redirect to the registration page, but for me this only happens after the page is refreshed.
What should I change in the Logout.js file so that when I click on the button Logout a redirect to the registration page?

Logout.js:

```
class Logout extends React.Component {

   deleteToken = () => {
      localStorage.removeItem('myToken');
   };

   render(){
      return (
         <button onClick={this.deleteToken}>Logout</button>   
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: If it’s just the logout button not sending you to the root page, why not use history.push(“/“) like you did to get to the home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `Home` component isn't getting updated / rendered after you remove items from `localStorage`.

One approach would be to reload the page when Logout is clicked:

```
class Logout extends React.Component {
  deleteToken = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('myToken');
    window.location.href = '/';
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.deleteToken}>Logout</button>   
    );
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you handle the `localStorage` API in asynchronous way.
You can use this way -> [Is any solution to do localstorage setItem in asynchronous way in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42921220/is-any-solution-to-do-localstorage-setitem-in-asynchronous-way-in-javascript/42922083)

or you can use `localStorage.removeItem('value');` with help of a `Promise`, then when the opration done, redirect to the authorization page.

good luck