# localstorage setItem() is not working in some cases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm using react reducer to handle a request for a deleting an item from the list:

```
case 'REMOVE_ITEM': {
      let products = state.products!
      for( var i = 0; i < products.length; i++){ 
    
        if ( products[i].id === action.payload) { 
          products.splice(i, 1); 
        }
      }

      let result = {...state, products: products, productSelected: products[0]}
      localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(result))
      console.log(result)
      return { ...state, products: products, productSelected: products[0]}
    }
```

When I click the first item everything works great, but when I delete other items, my state updating and `console.log(result)` work fine, but there are no updates to localstorage, so I assume that `setItem` is not launching.
I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me with this issue.

Comment: You are changing an array while iterating over it, which is bound to not work as expected. I guarantee that localStorage.setItem works absolutely fine, the issue is your code. Use Array.filter() to remove a product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, the state is immutable. In simple terms it means that you should not modify it directly. Instead a new object should be created to set the state using setState.

The `splice()` methods mutate an array.
`filter()` does not mutate the array on which it is called. It is better to do the following method :

```
const deleted=state.products.filter((item)=>item.id !=== action.payload)

return { ...state, products: deleted}
```

And if you want to store something in localstorage, it is better to use the lifecycle in the react:

`componentDidUpdate()` for class component
`useEffect` for functional component

Comment: Replacing `splice()` with `filter()` was not very helpful in this particular case (even though in general it's a good advice). However, moving `setItem()` to a function which renders the main page solved the problem: ```const state = useContext(GlobalProviderState); localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(state)) ```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that, when you are clicking it on the second time it is causing problem because of the synchronous nature of localstorage .

Try this

```
const asyncLocalStorage = {
    setItem: function (key, value) {
        return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
            localStorage.setItem(key, value);
        });
    },
    getItem: function (key) {
        return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
            return localStorage.getItem(key);
        });
    }
};
case 'REMOVE_ITEM': {
      let products = state.products
      for( var i = 0; i < products.length; i++){ 
    
        if ( products[i].id === action.payload) { 
          products.splice(i, 1); 
        }
      }

      let result = {...state, products: products, productSelected: products[0]}
      asyncLocalStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(result))
      console.log(result);
      return { ...result};
    }
```

Reference : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42921220/is-any-solution-to-do-localstorage-setitem-in-asynchronous-way-in-javascript)

Comment: Wrapping this with promises doesn't solve the issue. As pointed out above by soheiljafarnejad , they're modifying an array while iterating over it.

Comment: If so , then how is console.log showing correct output ?