# Is there a way to queue my JS functions to the JSF event queue?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

By default JSF ajax(JS) events are queued so that they are executed in order. Is there a way to hook into that framework?

What I am trying to do, is to get my JS events to use this queue as well. Is the global variable that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't, but you can hook an event listener on JSF ajax request(s) via `<f:ajax onevent>` and `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent`. You can then execute some JS code before the ajax request is sent, or after the ajax response is arrived, and/or after the HTML DOM is updated. Depending on the concrete functional requirement, that may be *actually* what you're looking for.

Here's how such an event listener function can look like:

```
function someAjaxEventListener(data) {
    var status = data.status;

    switch(status) {
        case "begin":
            // This is invoked right before ajax request is sent.
            break;

        case "complete":
            // This is invoked right after ajax response is arrived.
            break;

        case "success":
            // This is invoked right after HTML DOM is updated.
            break;
    }
}
```

And here's how you can register it on a per-`<f:ajax>` basis:

```
<f:ajax ... onevent="someAjaxEventListener" />
```

And here's how you can register it on a view-wide basis (thus, hooking on every `<f:ajax>`):

```
<h:outputScript>jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(someAjaxEventListener);</h:outputScript>
```

*(preferably put it in some JS file which you load by `<h:outputScript name>`)*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. These links also helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868434/are-calls-to-javascript-methods-thread-safe-or-synchronized , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575589/how-does-javascript-handle-ajax-responses-in-the-background?lq=1 , http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/jsdocs/symbols/jsf.ajax.html

Comment: Actually, although a **very bad** design, you could get hold of the `Queue` object and enqueue your requests there. BTW, the queueing mechanism for Multipart form is broken. If it queues one request, it will not process further requests. I raised the relevant bug: JAVASERVERFACES-3106