# Concurrency with singleton service in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a singleton service shared for all components like this.

```
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ItemService {
      items: Items [];

       addItem(item: Item){
       this.items.push(item);
       }
       getItems(){
      return this.items;
      }
    }
```

it's thread-safe to use common fields. this case doesn't cause a problem in concurrency ?

Comment: You don't have to worry about thread safety in JavaScript, this previous answer explains it better than I can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868434/are-calls-to-javascript-methods-thread-safe-or-synchronized

Comment: thx for your answer