# A method that calls an API using Axios isn't behaving sequentially

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

Given the following Vue method to call an API using Axios to fetch some data:

```
fetch: function() {

    console.log('Commence call to API!');

    axios.get("fetch.php")
        .then(response => {

            if (response.status === 204) {
                this.noContent = true;
            } else {
                console.log(response.data);
            }                    
        });

    console.log('Method complete!');                    
},
```

The expected in the console output should be as follows:

1. Commence call to API!
2. {{Some response data}}
3. Method complete!

Instead, what often happens is the following:

1. Commence call to API!
2. Method complete!
3. {{Some response data}}

How can I ensure that the method behaves in a 'sequential' manner?

Comment: [How do I set a specific order of execution when asynchronous calls are involved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497968/how-do-i-set-a-specific-order-of-execution-when-asynchronous-calls-are-involved) | The answer talks about `setTimeout`, but the concept is the same as an AJAX request.

Comment: Well it still deserve some explanation why axios is asynchronous using Promise.

Comment: There must be thousands of answers that explain the asynchronous nature of promises and AJAX. I dupe hammered this with one that has long, reasonable explanations, including two additional links on how to structure asynchronous code in the very first answer.

Comment: Yes the question you suggest seems to be very details on that subject but for a beginner it might not be obvious how is it related to `axios` ?