# Does Javascript have support for multithreading?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't JavaScript support multithreading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879/why-doesnt-javascript-support-multithreading)

Is there some way to spawn new threads for running tasks (for network stuff or some heavy calculations) to work in parallel?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879/why-doesnt-javascript-support-multithreading?rq=1

Comment: Keep in mind that *multi-threading* is a specific kind of *concurrency*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no.

You can use [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using_web_workers) to create background threads, but it's far from all browsers that support that. Internet Explorer for example doesn't have support for it until version 10.

In regular Javascript code there is no multi threading. Javascript is a strictly single threaded language.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, via  web workers. See documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using_web_workers

Answer (score 3):

You can, but only in modern browsers that support `Webworkers`

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Answer (score 1):

JS does not directly support multithreading but I believe you could emulate it by using several IFRAMES running a same script or different scripts. I'm just speculating.

Comment: Iframes run in the same thread as the top window.

Comment: Really? Is it true for all browsers? I thought IFRAMES were run in different threads :S

Comment: Very easy to test since jsfiddle code runs in a different iframe, if you make a `while(true){}` loop your whole tab/window will freeze.