# How to apply lock to 2 functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to apply a lock to 2 functions so that the 1st function gets executed 1st and then the second function executes when called simultaneously.

The 2 functions are :

```
function f1(){
   //some code here
}

function f2(){
   //some code here
}
```

Comment: Are they asynchronous?

Comment: try using callback process..

Comment: This might be your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879/why-doesnt-javascript-support-multithreading

Comment: @user2168945 - are you looking for plain javascript or JQuery solution?

Comment: yes they are ajax functions.

Comment: @user2168945 - Please provide more details. How are you actually calling the two functions. Some concrete code samples would be of great help. What do you mean that they are called simultaneously? Are they being queued in the event loop using `setTimeout`? Are they suspended and waiting for an external event to occur? Please be more specific when you ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

Functions in JavaScript aren't "called simultaneously" : there is only one user thread.

You don't have to put a lock, you have to look at how you call the functions. And probably you don't have to care.

If what you want is having two functions executed in order when the ajax requests are done, then you may use jQuery's [promise](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) system :

```
$.when($.ajax(...), $.ajax(...)).done(function(){
  f1();
  f2();
});
```

Comment: U mean only 1 function runs at a time. Because consider that both functions have a for loop in them then if after 3 iterations of 1st function I call 2nd then both functions iterations should be displayed i.e 1st function should continue from 4 and 2nd function should also start simultaneously