# is there a better phrase to talk about the threaded nature of languages like javascript

Tags: javascript, multithreading

This is a purely human problem and very likely a problem on my end.

We have a developer who every time Javascript is brought up emphasizes that it's single threaded on the server.

Is there a better phrase to describe Javascript single-threaded nature of having multi-threading implemented in libraries? I use the phrase multi-threading to only refer to when a user can create threads in user space (pthread_create for example) but I really dislike the idea of calling JS single-threaded (speaking of node here).

Words like concurrency or parallel are more problematic IMHO. Not looking for a long discussion of the nature but are there any suggestions to how to describe this? I think calling JS single-threaded is correct but is there another term? like lib-threaded or something? Maybe single-threaded non-blocking but too verbose.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about semantics and wording and not a code problem.

Comment: Calling JavaScript single-threaded is correct, thinking about it in any other terms in problematic and can lead to designs that only look efficient.  Now criticizing JavaScript for being single threaded is also misguided.

Comment: maybe better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @j08691 I consider this a software problem and hence a development problem.

Comment: @timpone - I'm sure you do, however SO isn't the best place to ask this question.

Comment: JavaScript is **evented**.

Comment: just reread ?, could certainly migrate to programmers.stackexchange.com. I don't think I can

Comment: I like evented as a description thx Bergi

Comment: others: "event-driven", "event based" programming. related post mentioning possible multithreading using webworkers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879/why-doesnt-javascript-support-multithreading

Comment: I call it bean-threaded

Comment: sounds like your co-worker is the one who is single-threaded. that's like complaining that cars need fuel...

Comment: desptite the comments I still think there should be another terms to reflect this - like I say in the original question, the issues isn't whether or not JS is multithreaded but that I think there should be a way to accurately reflect this in language.