# Browser code - get an unique ID per task

Tags: javascript, html

Without using Workers the javascript code is executed in a browser in a single threaded mode (check [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879/why-doesnt-javascript-support-multithreading)). To simplify we can say that a browser is going to call some js code on events, timeouts, and ajax returns waiting patiently for completion (if no you get a freeze).

Let's imagine this workflow :

1. Browser doing actual rendering
2. User clicks -> some js code starts and ends
3. a Timeout -> againg some js code is executed
4. Browser does something
5. User clicks again -> some js code start and ends
6. ... and so on

The questions, is there a way to have an unique Id from the browser each time so when logging some events we know it is a different task that is being executed ?

1. Browser doing actual rendering
2. User clicks -> some js code start and ends
   -> Log task 2 : doing something
3. a Timeout -> againg some js code is executed
4. Browser does something
5. User clicks again -> some js code start and ends
   -> Log task 5 : doing something (again)
6. ... and so on

Yes indeed we could build our code to manage this, but it's not the actual question.

Comment: Unique ids across all browsers? Doubt it. Unique id just for the current browser, sure. steTimeout Generates one, or just use a timestamp.

Comment: Me too, but who knows. It's more than one line that logs, so timestamp not ideal

Comment: Well there is nothing built into JavaScript that builds a GUID so make something.