# What are the main reasons in which Javascript was design to not be multithreaded?

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I'm wondering why JS hasn't evolved into a language that supports multithreading. I understand that we have the event loop model as the model of concurrency execution in the JS ecosystem. I realize this helps execute blocking tasks in a nonblocking way by essentially queuing up these tasks before invoking on the call stack. My question is mainly *why don't* we want multithreading in javascript? Is the issue mainly due to race conditions happening on the DOM and ruining the rendering on the page? I know that Node is more performant than Nginx (right?) due to the single threaded architecture for all requests, but just missing the *why* in all this?

Comment: You've combined a lot of half-truths into a largely inaccurate view of the situation.  Some things to think about... JavaScript is independent of browsers, the DOM, etc.  That's just a commonly used context.  Comparing the performance of Nginx to Node.js is like comparing the performance of a car to a blueprint.  Also, Node.js isn't single threaded.  Calls out to native libraries run threads all the time.  There are also various execution models that can be used in JavaScript, providing threading of various kinds.

Comment: I know node uses libuv to spawn threads for IO related activities. I guess I'm just wondering why javascript at the core is single threaded

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879/why-doesnt-javascript-support-multithreading

Comment: This thread talks about why staying away from multi-threading may make sense as a conscious decision: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/315454/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-making-a-multi-threaded-javascript-runtime-implementat