# Does JS support multi-threading now?

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I was perusing some answers but they were very old. Does somebody know about the latest development in this regard?

Also is there any chance that JS will become multi-threaded in the near future?

Related Question:-
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879/why-doesnt-javascript-support-multithreading)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Thread

Comment: No, Javascript is single threaded.  But you have had the ability to use multiple threads for a long time now with Webworkers that basically spins up another JS runtime were you can send / receive messages from.  Aka  IPC..  But due to the async nature of Browsers often Webworkers are overkill.

Comment: @Keith Your comment makes more sense as an answer to the question

Comment: No, A JavaScript context is single-threaded and will be single-threaded for the foreseeable future.  There may be many threads within the process, as is the case with Node.js and its many IO threads, but only one of them will be accessing the JavaScript context at a time, thus, from JavaScript's perspective it's still single-threaded.  There may also be multiple workers to achieve script concurrency, each with its own JavaScript context and thread, but they are isolated and data must be exchanged via passing messages. Workers don't have direct access to data or objects of other workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS in majority of browsers run on V8, which is essentially same engine used by Node.js

The very foundation of Node.js and the way it works is it has Event Loop on single thread - which is intentional. It removes any issues with synchronizations between threads and any overhead with creating/deleting threads. That is very important concept for backend as it often handles tens or hundreds of concurrent requests at once.

It makes also code very deterministic (you know that the synchronous part of the code taken by Event Loop will be executed fully before another event in Event Loop will be taken and processed)

However from the beginning - Node.js HAS thread pool. Another threads are used for I/O operations in background (like requests or handling files). You can create workers which does have their own threads if you like to.

Does the core of Node.js change? Most likely not, it would be breaking change and it would be actually against the main idea of Node.js. Also not bringing much benefits (as you can use more threads if you really want to already)

Comment: "*JS in browsers run on V8*" - in a few browsers. Not in all of them.

Comment: The argument "browsers use the same engine as nodejs, and nodejs has a thread pool" makes no sense, and does not answer the question.

Comment: Thank you. `Another threads are used for I/O operations in background (like requests or handling files).` This point helped me understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to access a separate thread is to use Web Workers.

You can either create a file for the worker:

```js
    /////////////////////////////////////////// Main (main.js)
    const worker = new Worker('worker.js')


    // Set up a listener for messages from the worker
    worker.onmessage = (message) => {
      // This is where you receive your worker response
    }

    // Error handling
    worker.onerror = console.error


    // This message will be passed to the worker
    worker.postMessage('hello worker')



    /////////////////////////////////////////// Web workers (worker.js)

    self.onmessage = (message) => {
      // message.data is where your passed parameter is stored
      const data = message.data
      
      // Execute some code
      
      // Send back a response to the main thread (main.js)
      postMessage(data)
    }
```

Or you can actually create a dynamic worker:

```js
    // main.js


    // This function will be passed into the worker
    function test(message) {
      const data = message.data
     
      // Response
      postMessage(data)
    }

    // Dynamic creation of a worker
    const bytes = new TextEncoder().encode(`self.onmessage = ${test.toString()}`)
    const blob = new Blob([bytes], {type: 'application/javascript'})
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    const worker = new Worker(url)


    // Set up a listener for messages from the worker
    worker.onmessage = (message) => {
      // This is where you receive your worker response
    }

    // Error handling
    worker.onerror = console.error

    // This message will be passed to the worker
    worker.postMessage('hello')
```

And 3rd variant is to use my own npm library [`@a4turp/threads.js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@a4turp/threads.js)

API is easy to use.

```js
    import Threads from '@a4turp/threads.js'

    // Creating new threads
    const threads = new Threads(4)

    // Task to execute on separated threads 
    function test(param) {
      param = param ?? 0
      // Note that passed message is directly accessible. So no `message.data` 
      
      // Execute some code
      
      // Just a regular return to get the message
      return param + 10
    }

    // @param task: Function to execute
    // @param message?: Parameter value of the function
    // Chainable
    threads.push(test, 20).push(test, 10).push(test)



    // Execution
    // You will get all responses in the same order you pushed tasks
    const result = await threads.execute()
```

Comment: These snippets are not runnable, so maybe best just to use regular code markdown rather than a snippet.

Comment: You are right, but the second snippet with a dynamic worker was actually working, I just had to console.log it.