# force "draft" rendering in browser

Tags: php, html, http, browser, rendering

Would it be possible to force a webbrowser reducing render quality to increase speed? I want to show big html-structures (`document.getElementsByTagName("*").length` returns 661844 elements).

At the moment the website needs about 2.8s to load the content (~13MB but gzip compressed), but the DOMContentLoaded event is triggered about 46s after start - this is far to long. Between pressing the "start button" and the DOMContentLoaded event the browser doesn't respond and therefore I want to reduce the time.

any suggestions?

Comment: Just 660k? Haha. Why not use AJAX? You won't be needing all these elements right from the start I reckon?

Comment: ok, its a old laptop, but it takes still to long. Why Ajax? This would only change the way I receive the data, but it still has to be rendered.

Comment: q@NaN: In most cases, you don't actually need all 660k elements right at the start of the page, instead you can simply AJAX a smaller chunk of data and load more as the user browses around. Forcing the user to download all 13MB of data before they can do anything is never a good user experience, especially if they really only need two of those items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "draft" rendering, but there are ways to prevent the browser from locking up: [Prevent long running javascript from locking up browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672732/prevent-long-running-javascript-from-locking-up-browser)