# Javascript - Script1 stops until script2 is running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two script.

**First:**

```
a = 0;
for (var i = 1000000000 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    a += i;
};
console.log(a);
```

**Secend:**

```
setInterval(function(){
    if (l.data('pos') == 0) {
        l.css('margin-left', '10px');
        l.data('pos', '1');
    }else{
        l.css('margin-left', '0');
        l.data('pos', '0');
    }
}, 100);
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/chalist/63sqr0gc/1/)

As you see, browser run second section after finishing first section.

Can I run first section in background and second section runs from document ready?

Comment: Javascript is single threaded language, meaning only running in one thread. But if your first section isn't requestiong/updating DOM, you could use on modern browser [webworkers](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/)

Comment: If web workers are not an option, then you could split computation in first script into small chunks with help of `setInterval`/`setTimeout`. Then it won't block UI and other scripts from execution.

Comment: @Victor may I ask how can I use `setTimeout` for this example? May give me a fiddle link? tnx

Comment: @chalist JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/63sqr0gc/3/ though the whole idea is already described e.g. in http://stackoverflow.com/a/672784/1235394

Comment: @Victor awesome. thanks dude :)

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is single threaded, however HTML5 Web Workers supports multithreading but you need to handle supporting old browsers.

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh549259.aspx