# How to prevent IE from freezing while long running script execution?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pdfmake

I'm experiencing quite long freezes of Internet Explorer while it's executing long run tasks. The task is about generating large PDF document using [pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake) and pure/vanilla javascript. So, that means **I dont have control of what this script do, I just call it**:

```
function getPdf(docDefinition, filename) {
    var t = Date.now();
    return pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download(fileName + '.pdf', function() {
        console.log('pdfMake.createPdf: \'' + fileName + '.pdf\' generated in: ' + (Date.now() - t) + 'ms');
    });
}
```

For some large docs it take more than 30sec while I cant do anything.

How to prevent of freezing, so I could display some spinning wait icon, or somthing else?

Comment: the only way is to use web worker. Otherwise, just put the process to create PDF into server. Browser just need to get the file.

Comment: If the library doesn't provide an asynchronous way of doing it, you are probably out of luck. As others have hinted at, if it were your own code that is locking it up it might make sense to shift some of the work to a web worker (although in this case I'm not sure that it would because all the data would need to be copied in and out of the worker via the structured clone algorithm, which is slow)  or split the work into several pieces over several `setTimeout` calls; if it is the library's processing that is the bottleneck you can't do anything about in your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent long running javascript from locking up browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672732/prevent-long-running-javascript-from-locking-up-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 10 IE supports [web-workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) which allow running JS on a different thread than the main thread.

Comment: It looks like what i was looking for. But now comes a new problem: how to pass `docDefinition` (which has some functions inside) to worker ?? It only allowes serialized data.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) returning a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), which will be resolved when pdf generator finishes his work.

**ES5**

You can use [this promise polyfill](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill)

Comment: I know, but I'm not allowed to use ES6 there (just pure/vanilla javascript and pdfmake.js)

Comment: This is why i've added the link with Promise polyfill made using vanilla js :)

Comment: this will not help the main thread from freezing, the async function is running on the same thread