# My AngularJS page stuck mobile version and google chrome console not show any error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, google-chrome

Our angularjs website got stuck as freeze and while google chrome developer console not showing any error message when I browsing my website with mobile view in Google chrome like that:

Testing scenario is when I've changed to mobile view and click on `All top companies hiring today` orange button located at the bottom, then click on one of companies there. Then, click logo of our website went got stuck as freeze. Please help me how to troubleshoot why page got stuck.

https://www.myjobs.com.mm/en/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Whenever any data pull request is getting executed from your application, UI gets blocked at that time and as the result whole page seem stuck to you.Use timeout to avoid this situation and optimise your code.Reference: [Prevent long running javascript from locking up browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672732/prevent-long-running-javascript-from-locking-up-browser)