# How to evaluate a javascript string and call functions from it (Without window)

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I'm working on a tool to help teach programming, and at a certain point, I am having clients send javascript as a string to a server. I am always going to call the functions A and B from their code, but I'm unsure of how to restrict their access?

What I'm doing right now:

```
eval(code);
userFunctionA = eval("getA");
userFunctionB = eval("getB");

var result = userFunctionA(param1, param2);
```

Unfourtunately by using eval, they have access to all of my global variables and other functions, how do I restrict their access?

Here's the best reference I found, but they are very concerned with "window", and since mine is a node server, I don't have a window, and I cannot use the suggested iFrame or worker: [Is it possible to restrict the scope of a javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020116/is-it-possible-to-restrict-the-scope-of-a-javascript-function)

Note: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me to break their string of code into functions before reading them, as this would disable learning things like:

```
function a() {fdafs}
b = a();
a = function (x){fsadg}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the `eval()` code its own Module then you get the benefit of the [`module wrapper`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper) that goes around each module when `require`'d. The module wrapper constrains global scope to the module. Basically, it is a form of namespacing.

So if you simply do

#### evaluator.js

```
module.exports = function(funcToCall) {
  eval(funcToCall);
}
```

#### app.js

```
const evaluator = require('evaluator');

evaluator(code);
```