# WebWorker without xmlhttprequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-worker

So from what I've read, to run a web worker, you:

```
var ww = new Worker('js/myscript.js');
```

This runs an xmlhttprequest for script.js, runs the code inside and does the normal callback work. Is there any way to avoid using ajax? E.g.

```
Function myFunction() { ... }
var ww = new Worker(myFunction);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web workers without a separate Javascript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408406/web-workers-without-a-separate-javascript-file)

Comment: "doing a HTTP request" is not equal to "xmlhttprequest"

Comment: Top link solves my problem. Thanks!