# Create a Javascript Worker passing an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, web-worker

In order to instantiate a new Worker, the logic is the following:

```
var w = new Worker("demo_workers.js");
```

`demo_workers.js` contains the definition of what the worker will do. Is it possible to avoid the creation of a new .js and pass an internal function to that constructor? Something like

```
var w = new Worker(
   function(){
       alert("hey!");
   };
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the specification states that you must reference a javascript source.

http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#worker

"Worker(scriptURL)" is the only option specified.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408406/web-workers-without-a-separate-javascript-file

Comment: Mattias points out something that is possible but might not be a good practice which he points out.  Either way both are urls which is what the specification.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a worker using a function, since this would cause a lot of concurrency problems. You need to pass a URL to a script.

However, you *can* use a URL for a `Blob` which you created at run-time. [MDN has a great example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers#Embedded_workers) where they create a worker using the contents of a non-evaluated `<script>` tag on the same page. This way, you can place the worker script on the same HTML page as the code using the worker, thus saving a HTTP request for the worker script. (Of course, if the worker script is static, it's probably better to keep it in a separate file which can be cached by the browser.)