# How can I inject a function into a script tag without including the wrapper syntax?

Tags: javascript, shared-worker

In this weird situation, I need to convert a JS function into a string, and then then that string into a dynamically generated `<script>` tag (which uses type `javascript/worker` so as to not be executed).

I'm working on a user script, injecting code to create a shared web worker between two third party sites. The thing about user scripts is you usually just want to use one file for the script's functionality, and web workers like to use a separate JS file for the worker. Well [there's a way around that using a Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6454685/5536767). However, remember I'm only working with a script file, not an HTML file for the user script, so I want to store this part (the shared worker code) as a function in my script:

```
var worker = function() {
  self.addEventListener('connect', function(e) {
    var port = e.ports[0];
    port.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
      var message = e.data;
      port.postMessage(message);
    });
    port.start();
  });
};
```

then use the `toString()` on it so I can inject it into a dynamically generated script tag in the third party pages, so it ends up like this without the script calling on any extra files:

```
<script id="worker1" type="javascript/worker">
    self.addEventListener('connect', function(e) {
        var port = e.ports[0];
        port.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
            var message = e.data;
            port.postMessage(message);
        });
        port.start();
    });
</script>
```

However using the `toString()` method results in the word `function` being included, as shown in this example:

> Remember I was going to append the function to a script tag with type
>   `javascript/worker` instead of `text/javascript` so the function
>   wouldn't be executed until it was converted to a blob and used as a
>   file source for the worker, but here I'm going to use
>   `text/javascript` so you can see the error when it executes.

```js
var worker = function() {
  self.addEventListener('connect', function(e) {
    var port = e.ports[0];
    port.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
      var message = e.data;
      port.postMessage(message);
    });
    port.start();
  });
};

var func = worker.toString();
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.id = "worker1";
$("head").append(script);

$('body').append(script);
$('#worker1').append(func);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

---

> Just so you can understand what I'm doing, because it might be confusing,
>   a function like this would then convert the above
>   non-executed script tag into a Blob and use that instead of an
>   external file to create the shared worker:
>
> ```
> var blob = new Blob([document.querySelector('#worker1').textContent], 
> { type: "text/javascript" });
> var sharedWorker = new SharedWorker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
> ```

---

So, how can I inject the contents of the function into a script tag without including the function wrapper syntax(`function (){`)?

Comment: you could take the string and wrap it in `(` ... `());` - turning it into an IIFE - just a thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string's methods to do this:

I think this can help you or something like this, to remove the function name.

```js
function test(){
      console.log('TEST TEST');
}

    var fBody = test.toString()
    var index = fBody.indexOf('{');
    var functionBodyAsArray = fBody.substring(index + 1);
    functionBodyAsArray = functionBodyAsArray.substring(0, functionBodyAsArray.length - 1);

    console.log(functionBodyAsArray );
```

Comment: Interesting approach, there's an error with your code though, because the opening and closing brackets are still there. And a `)` is missing from `console.log`. I suspected this kind of string manipulation or Regex would be difficult to do without risking some weird bugs messing up the inner code.

Comment: A shorter way i figured out was just use `var functionBodyAsArray = fBody.substring(index + 3, fBody.length - 1);`

Comment: But a small problem is if you were to add a space between the `()` and the `{`, the bracket isn't removed. This can be avoided, but some JS cleaning functions might add a space there.

Comment: @Viziionary if you will find the index of '}' how many spaces want to add it will not bring to a problem.