# Can I have additional root elements in a vue.js single file component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'd like to use the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408406/web-workers-without-a-separate-javascript-file/6454685) to have web workers in a component without having to handle additional files.

However, adding another `<script>` element seems not to work:

- it I add it before the component's script part it doesn't get recognized/found by `document.querySelector`
- if I add it after the component's script part, the component doesn't compile

The only solutions I've found are:

- source in a multiline string: ugly, messes up the editor
- script inside the template: even uglier, exposes innards

Any better solution out there?