# Web Worker With Inline Code Using TypeScript And Webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, web-worker

I am trying to use the following SO answer in order to start a web worker without a separate js file:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19201292

But I am using TypeScript and Webpack. And inside the function, I have a line like:

```
let a = new XYZ();
```

where `XYZ` is an exported class in another file.

But I get the

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: XYZ_1 is not defined"

error at runtime.

How can this be resolved?