# getImageData not the same after run through createImageBitmap

Tags: javascript, bitmap, html5-canvas, rgba, uint8array

I have a function which downloads an image, and saves the image data.  Based on user preference, it can save the image data in one of two ways - as an [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) [`Uint8ClampedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray), or as an [`ImageBitmap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap).  I'm using an image loading function to wait until the image is loaded before running my save function:

```js
function loadImage(src) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.crossOrigin = '*';
        img.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(img));
        img.src = src;
    });
}
```

The function which saves the image data is this:

```js
async function fetchAndSaveImage(priority) {
  const imageUrl = `some_url`;

  // Create a canvas, so I can write the image data to it and then call getImageData on it
  var transferCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  transferCanvas.width = transferCanvas.height = 256;
  var c = transferCanvas.getContext('2d');

  await loadImage(imageUrl).then((image) => {
    if (priority === 'speed') {
      c.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 256, 256);
      var pixelData = c.getImageData(0, 0, 256, 256);
      saveImage(imageName, pixelData);
    } else {
      createImageBitmap(image, 0, 0, 256, 256)
        .then((ibm) => saveImage(imageName, ibm));
    }
  });

}
```

In order to extract meaningful pixel data from my saved image, I have another function which also considers `priority`

```js
function getPixelData(savedImageData, xyPosition, priority) {

  let RGBA;

  if (priority === 'speed') {

    // Tile data in form of ImageData,
    // Simply need to get pixels from position in Uint8ClampedArray 
    RGBA = getRGBfromImgData(savedImageData, xyPosition.x, xyPosition.y);

  } else {
  
    // Tile data in form of ImageBitMap, 
    // need to call .getImageData for coordinate
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
    c.drawImage(savedImageData, 0, 0);
    var pixelData = c.getImageData( 
      xyPosition.x, xyPosition.y, 1, 1
    ).data;

    RGBA = {
      R: pixelData[0],
      G: pixelData[1],
      B: pixelData[2],
      A: pixelData[3],
    };
  }

  return RGBA;
}
```

Everything is working exactly as expected when the `priority` is speed.  The image is loaded, then written to a canvas, its image data gotten, and saved as the `Uint8ClampedArray`.  However, when using `priority = 'storage'`, I am getting inconsistent results.  Sometimes, it works as expected and I am getting back good RGBA values.  But many times, with certain image urls, I am getting all 0s for RGBA values (when for the same image urls, I get good RGBA values for `priority = 'speed'`.)

I also tried first doing a `c.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 256, 256)` and then `createImageBitmap(c.canvas)`, just to be sure the image data was there.  No change.  I also tried playing with `ImageBitmapRenderingContext`, but I can't `drawImage` on that, nor can I `getImageData` from it.

What is going wrong in the conversion of my image to an `ImageBitmap` and then later back to a `Uint8ClampedArray` that my values sometimes end up as 0s?  Is there a better way to store RGBA image data in memory that still allows fast retrieval of values?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You are not setting the outpit canvas width and heoht, so if the coords are more than 300,150 you will fall on non existing pixels. Also, could you show `saveImage` too?

Comment: Hooollly shnikies, so simple.  This fixed the issue.  Thank you!  `saveImage` is something very simple: `function saveImage(imageName, pixelData) = cacheObject[imageName] = pixelData`, where `cacheObject` is literally just an empry object for starters.  Though this function is also customizable by the user of the package.  Thank you again! If you make a formal answer I can mark it as such and give you a nice upvote sir.