# web workers without a server

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have script that can be downloaded/used as a serverless single html file and mostly do the same as it did when on a server.   Parts of it however use web workers.  I would like to get these also working server-less.  I made a worker via a blob. [Web workers without a separate Javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408406/web-workers-without-a-separate-javascript-file)

This solution still only works via server even though no external resources are being used. No errors are thrown.  Any thoughts on how to get thread like functionality in a no-server context?

Comment: What does server-less means here? The page is served from which protocol? How do you generate the Worker? Are you listening to its `onerror` event? Except in case of strong CSPs you should be able to run a Worker from a blob:// URL. Can you try this code: `w = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([\`postMessage('works')\`]))); w.onmessage = (e)=>console.log(e.data); w.onerror = console.error;`

Comment: My fault.  Your code works, as does mine.   I must have fat-fingered my test this morning.  Thanks!

Comment: Then please delete this question so people don't waste time trying to figure out what could have  happen.