# new Function() return last value?

Tags: javascript, eval, function-constructor

How do I return the last value from the `new Function()` constructor? Seems [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#return_value) does this by default, as well as [`vm.Script#runInContext`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#scriptrunincontextcontextifiedobject-options).

I just want to create a REPL in the browser (where I can do something like `2+2;` and it returns `4` in the output) like `eval`, but without the drawbacks of `eval` (local function scope access, `AsyncFunction`, etc...)

Comment: You’re looking for the value of a [completion record](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-completion-record-specification-type). Other than using `eval`, `new Function`, or something similar, these are not observable from within a JS script or module, as far as I’m aware.

Comment: `eval` often gets a bad name, yes, it has security concerns, but in your case a repl the user is actioning the request, and its not been say proxied, as that would be bad.  I would also say `new Function` would have the same issues here anyway.

Comment: @SebastianSimon hmm, yes, that is what I'm looking for. I don't mind using `new Function`, just looking to avoid `eval()`. It seems through that maybe `new Function` just doesn't support it? So I'll have to do something like `eval('(async function(){ ' + input + ' })()')`, because the REPL also needs to support asynchronous code w/ `await`s

Comment: After looking through the ECMAScript pseudo-code, it looks like this is just a limitation of Function objects. The entire section only mentions `Completion` once (so where's no real way to access completion records for functions). But this is something that `eval()` does return, as defined in the spec. So I guess eval is the only way

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to run something in isolated scope. There you can safely use `eval` without worrying about access to local scope variables of your page. Try something like this:

```js
function run() {
  const code = `
  self.onmessage = async (evt) => {
    let result;
    try {
      result = await eval(evt.data);
    } catch(err) {
      result = 'Error: ' + err.message;
    }  
    self.postMessage(result);
  };
  `;
  const blob = new Blob([code], {
    type: "text/javascript"
  });
  const worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    document.getElementById('out').value = e.data;
  }
  worker.postMessage(document.getElementById('repl').value);
}
```

```html
<label for="repl">REPL:</label>
<input type="text" id="repl">
<button onclick="run()">Execute</button>
<p/>
<label for="out">Output:</label>
<input type="text" id="out" readonly>
```

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6454685/1580941) answer :)

Comment: Ooooh, I would've never thought of this. This is a great idea!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this.

`new Function()` does not provide any way to access the ["Completion Records"](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-completion-record-specification-type) of it's invocation, according to the [ECMAScript specification part on Function objects](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-objects).

So if you need the last value, you have to use `eval()`