# Does a function wait for a called function to complete before continuing?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, function, abstract

So basically in the below example, if function1 is ran will it wait until function2 is finished running before test equals 1? Or will it execute function2 on a separate "thread" essentially running function2 and making test equal 1 at the same time? (I think that's what it's called, I'm not too knowledgeable in the whole multithreading thing).

```
function function1() {
    function2();
    test = 1;
}
```

Comment: It will wait for it then continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will wait for `function2` to complete.

There are ways to do multi-threading but they require some work, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036/javascript-and-threads) for some extra information.

Comment: Thank you for such a fast answer! Is there some way or technique to make it run function2 and test = 1 at the same time?

Comment: @Cains, follow the link :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your `function1` will wait for `function2` to return before continuing. However, your `function2` may call things like `setTimeout` which will themselves not run until `function1` completes but `function2` will still return before `function1` continues even if the code it set to run inside `setTimeout` has not run yet.

The `setTimeout` (and `setInterval`) functions do not work in separate threads but they fake it by running their code when everything else is finished.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question about how you have the implementation of `function2()` set up. However almost all javascript is executed in a sequential manner unless a `setTimeout()`, `setInterval()` or other event driven mechanic is used for its execution. This however is not true multi-threading, put simply it cheats by just waiting for the rest of the code to execute

However what you have there is saying you execute `function2()` then wait for it to complete and then execute `test = 1`, You can *almost* think of having `function2()`'s body as being inserted at the beginning of the `function1()` body. The keyword being "almost". But that should give you an idea of how the JS is executed. However, V8 (Google's javascript engine) can support pseudo-multithreaded environments. While this can technically be done with in normal run of the mill JS it becomes a very big mess very quickly for more information take a look at this [Tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/multi-threading-javascript/).