# Will calling window.setInterval open a new thread in chrome?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, performance, google-chrome

I've read that all browsers except chrome have javascript code running in a single thread. I'm not even sure if this is still true, but assuming it is: Will calling window.setInterval multiple times open multiple threads in chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` and `setInterval` ([spec link](http://developers.whatwg.org/timers.html#timers)) will run code asynchronously, but won't run code on a different thread. It will use main UI thread to run the code you provide after specified period of time. To use multithreading, take a look at [HTML5 Web Workers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh549259.aspx) (MSDN) or look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30197/966932) (stackoverflow).

Comment: its a bad idea to link w3school articles, check this link for details: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Fixing these to link to the developers version of the spec instead.